# Why my answer was deleted

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, specific-answer

I answered this question and automatically I was downvoted, an the answer was deleted, I think this is not correct

The question: [Can I use PHP reserved variable as my variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19353131/can-i-use-php-reserved-varible-as-my-variable/19353161?noredirect=1#comment28674497_19353161)

Comment: Your answer is not deleted.

Comment: @animuson Why I see my answeer gray?

Comment: Answers get greyed out when they hit a score of -3. It's explained [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22184/what-do-the-colors-on-stack-overflow-mean)

Comment: if your answer gets -3, it probably _should_ be deleted, however.

Comment: @JanDvorak yes, but I think that the downvote aren't correct...

Comment: The community can use their downvotes as they see fit, so long as they aren't abusing them.  My guess is that the community thinks there is something wrong with your answer.

Comment: @EmilioGort I think they are. See my comment under the answer.

Comment: @animuson thanks...I learn many new thing with the link of the code color on SO